# Why does my Magento observer get stuck in and endless loop?

Tags: magento, observer-pattern

My observer gets stuck in and endless loop. Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

*config.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <shipmentsave>
                <class>Company_Shipmentsave_Model</class>
            </shipmentsave>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <sales_order_shipment_track_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <shipmentsave>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>shipmentsave/observer</class>
                        <method>salesOrderShipmentTrackSaveAfter</method>
                    </shipmentsave>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_shipment_track_save_after>
            <sales_order_shipment_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <shipmentsave>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>shipmentsave/observer</class>
                        <method>salesOrderShipmentSaveAfter</method>
                    </shipmentsave>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_shipment_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <sales_order_shipment_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <shipmentsave>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>shipmentsave/observer</class>
                        <method>salesOrderShipmentSaveAfter</method>
                    </shipmentsave>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_shipment_save_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

*Observer.php:*

```
class Company_Shipmentsave_Model_Observer
{
    public function salesOrderShipmentSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        error_log("My observer called ....",0);
        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
            ->setNumber('1231354564')
            ->setCarrierCode('localdelivery')
            ->setTitle('Aramex');
        $shipment->addTrack($track);
        $shipment->save();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observer waits for a shipment to get saved, then saves a shipment, which causes it to receive another event (yadda yadda ad nauseum). You will need a way to either escape the loop or not have to save a shipment.

Can you move your event onto `sales_order_shipment_save_before` and then allow the normal shipment saving to take effect, or do you need the shipment to already have been saved to do your part of the logic?

If so, change the following line on your observer so that Magento uses it as a singleton:

```
<type>singleton</type> // changed from model
```

Then, create a variable in your class to track whether you've recursed yet. If so, then just return.

Alternatively, you could check to see if there are any tracking numbers already on the shipment and only save if there are not (and you add one). That will kill the recursion as well.

Let me know if one of those works for you.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: hi Joe,

thanks for replying.

i think you mean <code>sales_order_shipment_before</code> and not <code>sales_order_shipment_after</code> because i am already facing problem using <code>sales_order_shipment_after</code>

yes changing the event to <code>sales_order_shipment_before</code> worked for me.

but still curious to know how to use <code>sales_order_shipment_save_after</code> if ever i require.

regards,
saurabh

Comment: It's been a long time since you answered this, but can you provide some insight on how to setup the singleton variable that you talk about in your answer???

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
sales_order_shipment_save_after
```

and its working for me

Thanks :)